# Soma de todos os números inteiros dentro de uma List<int>

Tags: c#

Tenho um metodo:

```
public static int soma(params int[] n)
        {
            int resultado = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
            {
                resultado += n[i];
            }

            return resultado;
        }
```

No meu console:

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int>();

Console.WriteLine("Digite um numero");
numeros.Add(int.Parse((Console.ReadLine())));

resultado = soma(numeros); //Gera erro de conversão de list Generics para int
```

Estou com a dúvida de como passar uma lista de parametros inteiros que o usuario digita para o metodo. E também como deixa o usuário parar de digitar para efetuar a soma.
Ex: ele vai digitando [1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9] e quer para e somar, não estou sabendo o comando para interromper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dentro da função soma, meta a entrar uma variável do tipo List, e basta trocar esse 'for' por um 'foreach', ficara assim:

`public static int soma(List<int> nomedalista){
                 int resultado = 0;
                 foreach(int x in nomedalista){
                        resultado+=x;
                 }
return resultado;
}`